# Mootools Slideshow

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, css, mootools

I am using an image slideshow with thumbnails that I found online at the below website.  Does anyone know how I would change this slideshow so that the thumbnails are listed to the right hand side of the slideshow instead of listed below it.  If you go to the below link then click on view demo you can see how my slideshow currently works.  I'm sure it's probably a change in either the javascript or the css I have tried a bunch of changes but I still can't get the images to show in a column on the right hand side.  Any help would be much appreciated.

http://davidwalsh.name/slideshow-thumbnails-captions

Answer (score 0):

I've just made a fiddle example on how you could set your slideshow HTML+CSS. JS is the same and it doesn't change!

Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/KKVxC/

Comment: When I add that code to my page the preview window doesn't alternate between the three images.  It seems like the code doesn't see the existing javascript which is making the images rotate.

Comment: Can you report here your code please? So I can check what is wrong ;)